# How to get every digit from a number in C?

Tags: c, function, while-loop

**I have these variables:**

```
 int dividend;
 int divider;
```

**And I have the function :**

```
Divisibility7 (int num);
```

Those two variables will be at the main function, and the user will be asked to enter the dividend and divider, but in case the user enter the divider `7`, then, the function above will be called.

The problem is that I have to follow specific criteria to do this. So let's say the user will enter with the dividend `7203`. This happen :

> I. **Get the last digit of the number**.
>
> > Last digit: 3
>
> Ii.  **Multiply the last digit by 2**
>
> > 3 x 2 = 6
>
> Iii. **Get the value of the initial number**,  without the last digit.
>
> > 720
>
> Iv. **Subtract the initial value without the last digit** from the multiplication result.
>
> > fabs (720 - 6) = 714
>
> V. **Repeat the process until the result is a  value less than or equal to 70**
>
> Vi. **Compare the result with the table of contents** (0, 7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49, 54, 63, 70) for
>   Determine whether or not the number is divisible by 7

**Code :**

```
int res;
int x; 
int y;

int Divisibility7(int num) {

    int res;
int x;
int y;
int z;

    while(num > 70) {

    x = num % 10; // get the last digit from the number
    y = x * 2; // multiply the last digit by 2;
    z = num/10; // get the first digits from the number
    fabs(z - y); // subtract the first digits with the last digits;

    }
```

}

In the part of the while, the final fabs(z-y) returns what I want, to be the first digits subtracting the last number, but the problem is that the while stop there, I have to do something to make this while go till 70 or less.

PS : I need to check if the final number from the iterations, it's a number multiplied by 7, how can I do that ? And I can't use mod for this.

Comment: You seem to be in need of a Good C Book, not a question in SO.

Comment: You need to explain what exactly the problem is that you are facing. Also, in your loop condition, you compare `num`, but never seem to change it in the loop.

Comment: Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: @SouravGhosh My code it's really all wrong and messed up because the exercise ask to do that way. And I am new to the language C and the SO, so sorry, if I am wrong, I can delete this post.

Comment: Why the complicated algorithm instead of `return ( num % 7 ) == 0`? (And since I can't add another comment but have a few minutes to edit this one, thanks for explaining the exercise. It looks like you may be close on the loop, but you need to set `num` to the result of the `fabs` call. And then after the loop you can do your final test described in step vi. Also, please understand that Sourav did not mean to offend, but was actually providing some helpful advice. At this stage you really would benefit from either a good C book or any of the various online tutorials that are out there.)

Comment: @MichaelGeary Because I can't use, it's part of the exercise to do that complicated way.

Comment: Numbers don(t have digits. Their decimal representation has digits.

Comment: I am sorry for the question, and thanks for all the replies, I am new to the C, so yeah, I get to do those crap codes sometimes, and the exercise doens't help with this. But again, thanks for the patience.

Comment: Note that `fabs()` is a floating-point absolute value function from `<math.h>`.  There's also plain `abs()` function for the integer absolute value; it's declared in `<stdlib.h>`.  Whichever you use, you need to capture the value returned by the function in a variable.

Comment: `(0, 7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49, 54, 63, 70)` Hmm.... is it really `54`? Or shoul it be `56` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not changed num in your while loop . Also you do no return the value . Hope the following code will be ok for you .

```
int Divisibility7(int num) {

    int res,x,y,z;
    while(num > 70) {

    x = num % 10; // get the last digit from the number
    y = x * 2; // multiply the last digit by 2;
    z = num/10; // get the first digits from the number
    num = abs(z - y); // subtract the first digits with the last digits;

    }

 if(num == 0 || num == 7 || num == 14 || num == 21 || num == 28 || num == 35 || num == 42 || num == 49 || num == 54 || num == 63 || num == 70) {
    return 1;
}
else { 
    return 0;
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quickly answer, the code worked :).

Comment: Glad to help you .

Comment: may be a better `if` condition would be 
`if (num == 0 || (num <= 70 && num % 7 == 0))`.

Comment: @FahadSiddiqui `if (num % 7 == 0)` would do. However, notice the number `54` which isn't `n * 7`. But I guess that is just a typo from OP

Comment: because the question states `(0, 7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49, 54, 63, 70)` to be checked at the end.

Comment: Note: `x = num % 10;` will return a negative number if `num < 0`.

Comment: @FahadSiddqui Yes,it would be better, the problem is that I can't use mod for check that out, so I need to do like that, it makes the code be ugly, but still, works.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, but I think this is what are you trying to do:

```
int main (void)
{
    int number, lastDigitMultiplied;
    scanf("%d", &number);
    while(number > 70){
        //get the last digit and multiply it by 2
        lastDigitMultiplied = (number % 10) * 2;
        //subtract the initial value without the last digit from the multiplication result.
        number = number / 10 - lastDigitMultiplied;
    }
    if(abs(number) % 7 == 0)
        printf("The result is %d and it is a multiple of 7", number);
    else
        printf("The result is %d and it is not a multiple of 7", number);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a call to `abs()` in there.

Comment: Should I change the condition of the last `if` statement to `abs(number) % 7 == 0` ?

Comment: The problem is that for the sample input of `7203`, you're instructed to _Subtract the initial value without the last digit from the multiplication result._ but I see that the question then goes on to do the reverse: `fabs (720 - 6) = 714`. OTOH, that doesn't affect the result if `abs()` is used. It isn't clear whether each iteration is supposed to use 720 (the initial value without the last digit), or whether the next iteration should use 71 (714 without the last digit).  Grrrr; ambiguous questions.  But I believe the intent is that `number = abs(lastDigit - number / 10);` should be used.

Comment: @Jonanathanleffler No, the iteration its not supposed to use the 720 as initial, but in fact, any number, as well for the last digit.

Comment: But I need to check if the final number is in the multiplication of 7, how can I do that ?

Comment: To do that use `number % 7`. `%` returns the rest of `number / 7` and it the number is a multiple of 7 the rest will be 0 so if `number % 7` is `0`, the number is a multiple of 7.

Answer (score 0):

for divisibility against **7**, if you have a positive large `bigint` already formatted as a `string`, don't waste time with the regular method doing it 1 digit at a time.

powers of 10, **mod 7**, repeats every 6 rounds :

```
10^1  %  7  =  3  10^7   %  7  =  3  10^13  %  7  =  3
10^2  %  7  =  2  10^8   %  7  =  2  10^14  %  7  =  2
10^3  %  7  =  6  10^9   %  7  =  6  10^15  %  7  =  6

10^4  %  7  =  4  10^10  %  7  =  4  10^16  %  7  =  4
10^5  %  7  =  5  10^11  %  7  =  5  10^17  %  7  =  5
10^6  %  7  =  1  10^12  %  7  =  1  10^18  %  7  =  1
```

meaning, the effects of the digits `mod 7` stay identical as long as they're in chunks of 6 digits at a time.

the largest multiple of `6-digits` supported by `double precision FP` to full integer precision would be `12-digits` at a time.

So the way to do it is to right-align the digits by padding leading edge zeros to ensure string length is a ***multiple of 12***. Then simply add the digits **onto** each other, performing a single `mod % 7` operation once every **9000** or so rounds of the addition loop

—-  (that's when you run up against `2^53` limit; 9007 rounds if u wanna be pedantic about it)

example :

```
   x = 71400535477047763120175175402859619447790
       02233464423375355339031113233806609150957
```

> `x % 7 = 4`

now try summing up chunks of 12 :

```
007140053547704776312017517540285961944779
002233464423375355339031113233806609150957

007140053547      7140053547
704776312017    711916365564
517540285961   1229456651525
944779002233   2174235653758
464423375355   2638659029113
339031113233   2977690142346
806609150957   3784299293303
----------------------------
               3784299293303 % 7 = 4
```

it works exactly the same for any multiples of 6 : e.g. 6, 18, 24, and 30 --

```
00714005354770477631201751754
02859619447790022334644233753
55339031113233806609150957

312017   312017
517540   829557
285961  1115518
944779  2060297
002233  2062530
464423  2526953
375355  2902308
339031  3241339
113233  3354572
806609  4161181
150957  4312138
007140  4319278
053547  4372825
704776  5077601
-----   -------
_       5077601 % 7 = 4
```

> 

```
00000000714005354770477631201
75175402859619447790022334644
23375355339031113233806609150957

464423375355339031   464423375355339031
113233806609150957   577657181964489988
000000007140053547   577657189104543535
704776312017517540  1282433501122061075
285961944779002233  1568395445901063308
--------------------------------------- 
                    1568395445901063308 % 7 = 4
```

> 

```
00000000000000714005354770477
63120175175402859619447790022
33464423375355339031113233806
609150957

339031113233806609150957   339031113233806609150957
000000000000007140053547   339031113233813749204504
704776312017517540285961  1043807425251331289490465
944779002233464423375355  1988586427484795712865820
---------------------------------------------------
                          1988586427484795712865820  % 7 = 4
```

> 

```
000000007140053547704776312017517
540285961944779002233464423375355
339031113233806609150957

000000007140053547704776312017          7140053547704776312017
517540285961944779002233464423  517540293101998326707009776440
375355339031113233806609150957  892895632133111560513618927397

                                892895632133111560513618927397  % 7 = 4
```